# Написать скрипт вывода новостей из Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqlconnector

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Есть база данных называется **news** с таблицей в ней **New**.

Нужно создать php скрипт, который выводил бы таблицу в таком виде, как на втором фото. Структура таблицы на первом фото. Читал на эту тему, дошел до коннекта к безе данных, к сожалению, как правильно извлекать из нее данные и оформить все это в виде таблицы не понял.

```html
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','news');
$query = 'select * from New';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo "ID - ".$item['Что тут писать?']."<br>";
    echo "Date: ".$item['Что тут писать?']."<br>";
    echo "Top_news: ".$item['Что тут писать?']."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: покажите какие наработки у вас есть. что пытались, какой запрос делали и т.д.

Comment: Отредактировал сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за "ответы". Сделал сам.

```
 <?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="root"; 
$db_name="news";
$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);

  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `ID`, `Date`, `Top_news` FROM `New`", $link);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo $result['Date']." : ".$result['Top_news']. "<br>" ;
?>
```

Comment: И как ваш ответ совпадает с вашим вопросом? У вас на скриншоте заявлен вывод данных из БД в виде html-таблицы, да к тому же с использованием т.н. "зебры". А у вас в ответе нет ни html-таблицы, ни css-зебры.

Comment: Это легко сделать, главное для меня было понять как извлекать элементы из БД и выводить их

Comment: Ну дык дело не в том, что сложно или легко, а в том, что ваш ответ не соответствует вашему вопросу. Вам нужно или переформулировать вопрос _(использовать ссылку "править")_, или дописать корректный ответ _(так же  использовать ссылку "править" для ответа)_, или просто удалить этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Ответом на ваш вопрос может быть примерно такое решение *(css отредактируете под ваши предпочтения)*:

```
$conn   = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'news');
$query  = 'SELECT * FROM new';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$data   = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo '<table border="1" style="background:grey;">'.
    '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Top_news</th></tr>';

foreach ($data as $i => $item) {
    $color = $i & 1 ? 'grey' : 'white';
    echo '<tr style="background:' . $color . '"><td>' . 
        $item['id'] . '</td><td>'.
        $item['date'] . '</td><td>' .
        $item['top_news'] . '</td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже набросал нечто подобное, но всегда приятно глянуть на хорошее решение.